# How to selectively map values into columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (df1,df2), i would like to replace the values in df1 based on the column. The df2 provides the different values according to the column defined in df1.
Query for df1 and df2 is follows

```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame({"user": ["user1", "user2", "user3"], "p1": ["A", "C", "C"],"p2": ["B", "B", "A"],"p3": ["C", "A", "B"],}, index=[0, 1, 2], )
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({"player": ["A", "B", "C"], "p1_score": ["3", "5", "4"],"p2_score": ["2", "4", "3"],"p3_score": ["1", "2", "6"],}, index=[0, 1, 2], )
```

df1 looks like this

[image]

df2 looks like this

[image]

my desired new dataframe should look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `df.replace` after modifying df2 col names to match df1 col names:

```
df1.replace(df2.set_index("player").rename(columns=lambda x: x.split("_")[0]))
```

---

```
    user p1 p2 p3
0  user1  3  4  6
1  user2  4  4  1
2  user3  4  2  2
```

Comment: thanks @anky , what if the column name p1,p2 and p3 were same for both df1 and df2? how would the code look like..?

Comment: @ArunMenon `df1.replace(df2.set_index("player"))` get rid of the `df.rename` part then.